# Hyper-V on Windows 8 host: run VM as a service?

Tags: boot, remote-desktop, windows-8.1, services, hyper-v

I have this **CURRENT setup** for two people to work:

1. Vista computer running VM Ware Server 2.0
2. Windows XP Virtual Machine running inside that host, accessed remotely via RDP

So, it's a single hardware PC with two systems running, one native and one virtual. Of course, the remote access requires some hardware also (in this case, an nComputing zero-client).

I want to change this to the following **NEW setup**:

1. Same hardware, but system upgraded to Windows 8.1 Pro with Hyper-V feature.
2. Windows 7 Pro virtual machine inside that host, accessed remotely via RDP

My question is this: how can I make sure that the Win7 VM is available remotely at all times? The current VMWare Server runs "as a service", starts automatically at boot and keeps going even if no one is logged on at the host.

What about Windows 8 Hyper-V host? **Is it able to startup VM's automatically at boot**? **Can it run VM's as a service**, without requiring a user log on at the host?

Of course, I tried Googling for answers but it's confusing because it's hard to keep Google from finding lots of things regarding Windows Servers with Hyper-V... this is just Windows 8.

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: You should be able to start Hyper-V through the command line.  I doubt it can be ran as a service.  Solutions that exist for Windows Server are very likely to work for Windows 8.

Comment: If anybody has actually tried it and has more solid information on this I would appreciate it.